# CMIS Producer in Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, cmis

I have to figure out how the CMIS support in SP2013 foundation does work out. And everything I find says that it is natively supported. But the site feature 'Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) Producer' does not exist. So I downloaded and installed the trial version of SP2013 Standard Edition and there it is... Already found out that the CMIS Producer was not a part of the preview but I installed the RTM release. So is it like in 2010 that CMIS is only available for Standand and Enterprise Edition? - because the site feature list says that it is also available for foundation ([http://office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/activate-features-for-sites-HA102772224.aspx))

Edit:
Called Microsoft support and there is definitely no CMIS producer in SP2013 Foundation (but in Server Standard / Enterprise). The agent also clarified that there is no difference in editon features between SP2010 and SP2013 (no CMIS Producer in SP2010 Foundation = no CMIS Producer in SP2013 Foundation).

Thanks to everybody helping investigate in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called Microsoft support and there is definitely no CMIS producer in SP2013 Foundation (but in Server Standard / Enterprise). The agent also clarified that there is no difference in editon features between SP2010 and SP2013 (no CMIS Producer in SP2010 Foundation = no CMIS Producer in SP2013 Foundation).

Thanks Arsalan for participating

Answer (score 0):

Swarley,

The article you have given on the top-right corner says:

> Applies to:
>   SharePoint Foundation 2013, 
> SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise, 
> SharePoint Server 2013 Standard

So the feature list is for all.. and AFAIK, till now there isn't any list that gives the feature difference between editions as it was [defined for SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx)

Comment: Yes, exactly, but the feature is not available in Foundation. Which means that I am missing some configuration in SP Foundation or the information on the given website is wrong... So has somebody installed SP 2013 Foundation on which the site feature 'Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) Producer' is available. Thanks